# "No route to host" after remote machine reboot

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, ping

After rebooting the remote machine (`sudo reboot`) and attempting to connect to it through ssh I am getting "No route to host". Before rebooting everything was fine.

I tried nmap, to check whether port, which I used to connect through is still open. The result is:

```
Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2018-03-01 16:10 EET
Nmap scan report for myservercomes.here (128.214.64.122)
Host is up (0.00075s latency).
rDNS record for 128.214.64.122: blablabla.fi
PORT      STATE    SERVICE
22135/tcp filtered unknown
```

How can I reach the machine now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid the remote machine didn't come back up, or if it did, it didn't bring up the IP address you're expecting. You'll have to get in out of band and diagnose it from there.

Comment: that's the only way which helped. the kernel was updated and some crash happened.